# Factor $a(a-2b+1)-b(3b+11)-6$ in $(a-3b-2)(a+b+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I factor this out by making linear combinations with these unknowns? I just thought : $a^2-a(2b-1)-3b^2-11b-6=0$, and this equation has $\Delta=(4b+5)^2\geq 0$.
So $a=\frac{-1+2b+4b+5}{2}=3b+2$, or $a=\frac{2b-1-4b-5}{2}=-b-3$

Comment: Your question is confusing.  What are you looking for?  The title seems to be the answer.

Comment: Your method seems correct. Are you asking for an alternative way to factor the expression?

Comment: I wonder how I do it manually using factoring / notable products

Comment: @David That's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in with a third variable to make it homogeneous quadratic, I get
$$ x^2 - 3 y^2 - 6 z^2 - 11 yz +zx -2xy = (x-y + \frac{z}{2})^2 - 4 (y + \frac{5z}{4})^2  $$
OR
$$ x^2 - 3 y^2 - 6 z^2 - 11 yz +zx -2xy = (x-y + \frac{z}{2})^2 -  (2y + \frac{5z}{2})^2  $$
which is a difference of squares. As in $A^2 - B^2 = (A+B)(A-B) \; . \;$ In the end, put back $z=1$
We get
$$ (x+y+3z)(x-3y-2z)  $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 6 &  - 11 \\ 
1 &  - 11 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 7 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 8 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 8 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 4 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 6 &  - 11 \\ 
1 &  - 11 &  - 12 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Can't do it manually without linear algebra? Only elementary manipulations